# Mongoose `findOne` operation times out after 10000ms

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

This error is really frustrating especially as it is intermittent (it comes and goes). I'm using mongoose with express and typescript and I'm connecting to a database on MongoDB atlas. This is resulting into a bad user experience and it isn't really cool. The error message displayed says `Operation wallets.findOne() buffering timed out after 10000ms`. There are times the app runs fine and executes all operations as purposed but this error suddenly creeps out at some point. Below is my code and if you read through it, you'd see I'm using async await.

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import { Wallet } from "../../core/interfaces";
import { Tokenizers } from "../../core/utils";

export class WalletModel {
  model: mongoose.Model<any>;

  constructor() {
    this.define();
  }

  private define() {
    this.model = mongoose.model(
      "Wallet",
      new mongoose.Schema({
        encryptedPrivateKey: String,
        encryptedWallet: {
          type: String,
          required: true
        }
      })
    );
  }

  async create(wallet: Wallet, privateKey: string): Promise<Wallet> {
    const encryptedWallet = Tokenizers.encryptWallet(wallet);
    const walletModel: any = await this.model.create({
      encryptedPrivateKey: Tokenizers.encryptPrivateKey(
        privateKey,
        wallet.publicKey
      ),
      encryptedWallet
    });
    const decryptedWallet: Wallet = Tokenizers.decryptWallet(
      walletModel.encryptedWallet,
      wallet.privateKey
    );
    return Promise.resolve(decryptedWallet);
  }

  async getWallet(privateKey: string, publicKey: string): Promise<Wallet> {
    const encPrivateKey: string = Tokenizers.encryptPrivateKey(
      privateKey,
      publicKey
    );
    // Below find utilizes the indexing created on encryptedPrivateKey field
    // and is way faster than linear search on whole collection
    const encWallet: mongoose.Document & {
      encryptedPrivateKey: string;
      encryptedWallet: string;
    } = (await this.model
      .findOne({
        encryptedPrivateKey: encPrivateKey
      })
      .lean()) as mongoose.Document & {
      encryptedPrivateKey: string;
      encryptedWallet: string;
    };
    const encryptedWallet: string = encWallet.encryptedWallet;
    const decryptedWallet: Wallet = Tokenizers.decryptWallet(
      encryptedWallet,
      privateKey
    );
    return Promise.resolve(decryptedWallet);
  }

  async findByPrivateKey(privateKey: string): Promise<Wallet> {
    let wallet: Wallet = null;
    const allWallets = (await this.model.find().lean()) as any;

    for (const doc of allWallets) {
      const pk = Tokenizers.decryptPrivateKey(doc.encryptedPrivateKey);
      if (pk === privateKey)
        wallet = Tokenizers.decryptWallet(doc.encryptedWallet, privateKey);
    }

    return Promise.resolve(wallet);
  }

  async updateWallet(privateKey: string, newWallet: Wallet): Promise<Wallet> {
    // const allWallets = await this.model.find();
    let w: Wallet = null;
    const updatedWallet = (await this.model
      .findOneAndUpdate(
        {
          encryptedPrivateKey: Tokenizers.encryptPrivateKey(
            privateKey,
            newWallet.publicKey
          )
        },
        {
          encryptedWallet: Tokenizers.encryptWallet(newWallet)
        },
        {
          new: true
        }
      )
      .lean()) as mongoose.Document & {
      encryptedWallet: string;
      encryptedPrivateKey: string;
    };
    w = Tokenizers.decryptWallet(updatedWallet.encryptedWallet, privateKey);
    return Promise.resolve(w);
  }
}
```

Here's the content of the index.ts file where I'm starting all servers and making connections:

```
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import config from "./config";
import { Environment } from "./env";

let app: express.Application = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 7890;

app = config(app);

app.listen(port, async () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${port} in ${process.env.NODE_ENV}`);
  const mongo = await mongoose.connect(
    Environment.MONGO_URI[process.env.NODE_ENV],
    {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useFindAndModify: false,
      useCreateIndex: true
    }
  );
  if (mongo) console.log("Connected to mongodb");
});

// Export app for tests
export default app;
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding the index: true in your mongoose model. This can also happen if the database record is large, so making indexes can help find the document fast.